# tags: variable-binding and scoping

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

While [recently editing a question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/14625/revisions), Raphael introduced the tag
[scoping](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scoping), using it to replace [variable-binding](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variable-binding) that had
been chosen by the OP. That is apparently the only use of [scoping](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scoping).

I must say, I did not understand the motivation for that, as scoping
is a subtopic of binding (though the word binding is often not used
alone). Still, I believe the two concepts are not separable, and thus
do not justify two tags in my opinion. Binding is a bit more general
as it may includes for example discussion of the uses of binding for
different purposes: quantification, abstraction, .... But binding
always implies some scoping policy.

I would suggest keeping both as synonyms, as binding may be more
naturally used by theoreticians, while scoping may be used more by
programmers. Actually, my preferred choice would be [name-binding](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/name-binding).

Comment: I've retagged that question back to [tag:variable-binding].

Answer (score 4):

I don't get the tag [scoping](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scoping) either, [variable-binding](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variable-binding) is fine for that question. I'm not convinced we need [scoping](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scoping) at all and I'd prefer [variable-scope](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variable-scope) if we introduce a synonym.

The proper tag name is [variable-binding](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variable-binding) and not [name-binding](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/name-binding), because [variables aren't always named](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index).

I speak a domain expert as a (former) programming language theoretist and also as a programmer.

Comment: Actually, though historical, the use of the word `variable` is
misguided in a programming context, since the issue concerns the
meaning of names, which may or may not denote variables. It would be
more acceptable in a purely mathematical context where `variable`
often means name. See for example: [What is the difference between assignment, valuation and name binding?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/39525). I know of de Bruijn notation, but ... it is not the most frequent use. And most discussions are about binding: what name means what, where. De Bruijn is only doing away with it.

Comment: @babou Your answer there is oversimplified. Posting a more complete one is on my to-do list. Variables are not always names (as scoping issues show, you can have multiple variables with the same name; and you can have variables without names, e.g. in De Bruijn notation) and are not exactly objects (e.g. in purely functional languages, variables are not objects at all).

Comment: I was expecting you to answer that. I was answering a question, and I
was attempting to be very simple and intuitive. My teaching
experience, and my contact with the OO crowd, taught me to be modest
in attempting to convey ideas.  I try to refer to the concepts they
use, though often ill defined. I have been doing my part of research
in programming languages and formal semantics. But I was only trying
to give a reasonably short answer to a (good) question that was mixing
issues. In a pure functional language, there are no variables in the
programming sense, only bindings denotations to values.

Comment: What I meant is that we usually try to answer questions in a digestible way. We are not supposed to write textbooks, not even a chapter.  And I do tend to write long and precise answers.

Comment: Completely fine with me, that tag was a shot from the hip.